# Scroll to top using jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this piece of jquery to scroll the page up to the top. It's not scrolling at all.

I've tested it using an alert() and it is triggering - so why isn't it scrolling to the top?

```
$(document).on("click",'.campaign-stats', function(event) {     
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Please note that the page does contain content inserted using AJAX, but I don't see how that would stop it scrolling to the top?

Comment: did you notice any error or warning in Web Console?

Comment: no warnings I'm afraid :(

Comment: can u pls create a fiddle?

Comment: That code looks fine, and appears to work: https://jsfiddle.net/m4t00khk/ Have you checked that jQuery has loaded correctly? Could you please setup a http://jsfiddle.net example which shows the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kau8px5k/1/ - looks fine

Comment: It must be to do with AJAX somehow. Sadly I can't create a fiddle because it's an insanely complicated backend interface system.

Comment: @AmyNeville then you might have some invalid structure. can you post the generated markup?

Comment: Your testing with `alert` leads me to believe that you should read about [the browser's developer tools](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). Once you're familiar with them, insert a breakpoint just before the scroll is supposed to happen and inspect what the DOM looks like at that moment and you might get some clues to what's wrong.

Comment: @ekuusela yes there's so many things I need to learn :)

Comment: Can you post the css of your html, body ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant `CSS`, `HTML` and more of your `JS`?

Comment: scroll(0,0) didn't work either....

Comment: @IvanModric it's printed as minified html by php/ajax on the server side

Comment: @AmyNeville  You could beautify it :) http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Comment: It's a massive pile of nested ajax containers - I'm not sure how beautiful you'd find it :P document.getElementById('header-logo').scrollIntoView(); this seems to work - is there any way I can animate this using jquery?

Comment: Can you link any working example? (Doesn't have to be a fiddle either)